# C# linq similar range list

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, c#-4.0

I am creating similar properties list.

I have to look for the 4 similar range properties in the list.

- If the price is $400,000 then I have to find 4 properties of $400,000 price.

If the 4 properties could not be found then

- Sort the list high to low and find the remaining properties from the list.

If there are no same price properties then

- Sort the list from high to low and get two properties from the list
- And again sort the list low to high and get the 2 properties from the
  list

In order to find the same price properties

```
var properties = props.results.Where(x => x.Price== price).ToList().Take(4);
```

High to low list

```
var highToLow = props.results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Price).ToList().Take(4);
```

Low to high list

```
var lowToHigh = props.results.OrderBy(x => x.Price).ToList().Take(4);
```

The problem is

When there is less than 4 properties found from the same price properties

```
var properties = props.results.Where(x => x.Price== price).ToList().Take(4);
```

Now I am sorting the list High to Low and finding rest of the properties from this High to Low list.

```
var highToLow = props.results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Price).ToList().Take(4);
```

How can I combine the list ?

Has anyone done something similar to what I am trying to achieve. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your class structure is needed

Comment: `How can I combine the list ?` `Concat` or `Union`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *Enumerable.Union*:

```
var result=  properties.Union(highToLow)
```

If your list is a list of objects then you should implement an equality comparer that can be used in the Union method. [Enumerable.Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.7.2)